# При изменение ориентации выдает ошибку. Android

Tags: android, xml, activity, android-xml

Есть два макета разметки с одинаковым именем один для макета под горизонтальную ориентацию а другой под вертикальную. Когда перехожу из одного положения в другое то приложение стопаеться и выдает ошибку

```
08-02 17:36:37.276 21801-21801/ru.landmarkstd.educt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: ru.landmarkstd.educt, PID: 21801
                                                                  Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, iconPack:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, fontPkg:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle}
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.landmarkstd.educt/ru.landmarkstd.educt.SelectActivity}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment ru.landmarkstd.educt.Fragments.TextAndImageFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4111)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                   Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment ru.landmarkstd.educt.Fragments.TextAndImageFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:441)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:105)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:2047)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState(FragmentController.java:158)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:324)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:85)
                                                                      at ru.landmarkstd.educt.SelectActivity.onCreate(SelectActivity.java:42)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4111) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<ru.landmarkstd.educt.Fragments.TextAndImageFragment> has no zero argument constructor
                                                                      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:430)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:105) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:2047) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState(FragmentController.java:158) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:324) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:85) 
                                                                      at ru.landmarkstd.educt.SelectActivity.onCreate(SelectActivity.java:42) 
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4111) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

вот код активити

```
public class SelectActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    Toolbar toolbar;
    String tag;
    Resources resources;

    FrameLayout frameLayout;

    ArrayList<itemList> itemLists = new ArrayList<itemList>();
    ArrayList<String> pathes = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select);

        resources = getResources();

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        new NavigationDrawer(getApplicationContext(), this, toolbar);

        tag = getIntent().getStringExtra("tag");

        switch (tag)
        {
            case "orph":
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.orph));
                break;
            case "arif":
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.arif));
                break;
        }


        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FragmentLayout);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        ////// Тестовая структура ///////////////////////////////////////
        itemQuestion itemQuestion = new itemQuestion("2*2", null, 20,2);

        ArrayList<itemQuestion> itemQuestions = new ArrayList<itemQuestion>();
        itemQuestions.add(itemQuestion);

        itemLists.add(new itemList("Таблица на два", "arif", itemQuestions));

        itemQuestion itemQuestion2 = new itemQuestion("C(о)рока", null, 20,10);

        ArrayList<itemQuestion> itemQuestions2 = new ArrayList<itemQuestion>();
        itemQuestions2.add(itemQuestion2);

        itemLists.add(new itemList("Слова на о", "orph", itemQuestions2));

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        if (itemLists.size() != 0)
        {
            SelectRecyclerViewFragment frag = new SelectRecyclerViewFragment(itemLists, pathes);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.FragmentLayout, frag).commit();
        }

        else
        {
            TextAndImageFragment frag = new TextAndImageFragment(1);

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.FragmentLayout, frag).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu_select, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.addElement:
                addElement();
                return true;
            case R.id.play:
                play();
                return true;
            case R.id.sortElement:
                sortElement();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public void addElement()
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, AddElementActivity.class).putExtra("itemList", new itemList("","",null))
                .putExtra("path", ""));
    }

    public void play()
    {

    }

    public void sortElement()
    {

    }
}
```

Вот первый макет под вертикальное положение

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ru.landmarkstd.educt.SelectActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/FragmentLayout"></FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Вот второй макет под горизонтальное положение

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/annonce.main.coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/flexible.example.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/flexible.example.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="94dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@null"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="80dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/FragmentLayout"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Лог ссылает все ругательства на эту строчку `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`  `(42:1)`

Если перехожу в это активити с предыдущего активити под нужный ориентацией например под горизонтальной или вертикальной, то макеты отображаються хорошо

Код класса TextAndImageFragment

```
public class TextAndImageFragment extends Fragment
{

    int CodeError;
    public ImageView imageView;
    /*
    1-Листов еще нету
    */

    public TextAndImageFragment(int CodeError)
    {
        this.CodeError = CodeError;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text_and_image, container, false);

        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        switch (CodeError)
        {
            case 1:
                imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_error_nolists));
                textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.error_NoLists));

                imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), AddElementActivity.class).putExtra("itemList", new itemList("","",null))
                                .putExtra("path", ""));
                    }
                });
                break;
        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не создавайте конструкторы фрагментов с параметрами! У вас должен быть конструктор без параметров. В вашем случае я бы сделал статический метод по созданию экземпляра фрагмента следующим образом:

```
public static TextAndImageFragment getInstance(int CodeError) {
   TextAndImageFragment fragment = new TextAndImageFragment();
   fragment.CodeError = CodeError;
   return fragment;
}
```

Все конструкторы фрагмента удалите